# How to add a class if both exists within a element

Tags: jquery

I'm more then confusing myself on how to get this done. I have multiple sets of tables wrapped in div calss "test" , within each table i need to find out if a class "hello" is present in each of the tablrows. If so , addClass to the parent div.

Example HTML - this div.test has tr which both contain a div class "hello" , so i want to add class to it.

```
<div class="test">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
     <td><div class="hello"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
     <td><div class="hello"></div></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

This div.test has only one tr which contains a div class "hello" , so no class should be added.

```
<div class="test">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
     <td><div class="hello"></div></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

The result should be this

```
<div class="test has_hello">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
     <td><div class="hello"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
     <td><div class="hello"></div></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>


<div class="test">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
     <td><div class="hello"></div></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

I tried adding a class using each tr , but it adds the class if either of the tr has .hello

```
jQuery('.test table tr').each(function(){ 
    $(this).has('.hello').closest('div').addClass('has_hello');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd iterate over each `<tr>` and if `.every` one of them has the `.hello` class, add the new class to the parent:

```js
$('.test').each(function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  if ([...$this.find('tr')].every(tr => $(tr).find('.hello').length !== 0)) {
    $this.addClass('has_hello');
  }
});
```

```css
.has_hello {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td><div></div></td>
     <td><div class="hello"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
     <td><div class="hello"></div></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="test">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>b</td>
     <td><div></div></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><div></div></td>
     <td><div class="hello"></div></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: that is not working on fiddle i setup  https://jsfiddle.net/d9vnfoa3/

Comment: Oh, you have multiple `.test`s with multiple tables in a single page? You have to iterate over the `.test`s instead then

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".test").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("tr").length == $(this).find(".hello").length;
}).addClass("has_hello");
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation of what you are achieving here.

Comment: Tanveer Badar //
The following code selects .test with the same number of tr and .hello counts, and pastes .has_hello. What explanation do you need?